# Good project ideas for high school physics club?

Tags: experimental-physics, education

I will be running the physics club with a friend at school this year. We are looking for projects to do that would take from 3 weeks to 2 months to do by working approx 3-4 hours per week. Last year we made a seismometer, for example. We are really interested in reading the ideas you have!!

Comment: Yeah, the question is much too broad for the purposes of this site. Maybe coming up with a list of your own ideas and asking for input would work better.

Comment: I think a [Cavendish pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment) would be a great experiment... infinite opportunities to make things "better".